# How to download last modified file from remote server to local using PuTTY batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, automation, putty, pscp

I have a query regarding the putty batch file. This is my `.bat` file:

```
C:
cd Program Files (x86)\PuTTY
pscp -2 -v -pw khair1 -sftp  abc@****.na.ab.com:/qwe/asd/tryu/*.csv.zip P:\Projects\abc\Test_bacth\Batch_download
pause"
```

So every week I have to give file name like `/qwe/asd/tryu/**04242016***.csv.zip`

How can I dynamically get all the file which is last modified.

Comment: There is a good description of doing this with UNIX/Linux commands at http://superuser.com/questions/524974/is-it-possible-with-scp-to-only-copy-files-that-match-a-certain-date If you can install http://www.cygwin.com/ it would probably work well.

Comment: If you are permitted to install PuTTY, then you are probably permitted to install WinSCP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use these commands to generate the today's stamp:

```
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims==" %%i in (`wmic os get LocalDateTime /VALUE 2^>NUL`) do if '.%%i.'=='.LocalDateTime.' set LDT=%%j
set STAMP=%LDT:~0,4%%LDT:~4,2%%LDT:~6,2%
echo %STAMP%
```

See [How do I get current datetime on the Windows command line, in a suitable format for using in a filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/203090/850848)

---

Or use some more powerful SFTP/SCP client.

For example with [WinSCP scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation), you can do:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" /command ^
    "open sftp://abc:password@****.na.ab.com/ -hostkey=""ssh-rsa 2048 xxxxxxxxxxx...=""" ^
    "get /qwe/asd/tryu/%%TIMESTAMP#yyyymmdd%%*.csv.zip ""P:\Projects\abc\Test_bacth\Batch download\""" ^
    "exit"
```

See [documentation for the `%TIMESTAMP%` syntax](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#timestamp).

---

If the timestamp is actually not today's, instead of specifying the timestamp, just download the latest file for each pattern/mask.

It's easy with WinSCP, just use the [`-latest` switch](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_get#latest):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" /command ^
    "open sftp://abc:password@****.na.ab.com/ -hostkey=""ssh-rsa 2048 xxxxxxxxxxx...=""" ^
    "lcd ""P:\Projects\abc\Test_bacth\Batch download""" ^
    "cd /qwe/asd/tryu" ^
    "get -latest *_cpg_aob_detail.csv.zip" ^
    "get -latest *_fmcg_cob_detail.csv.zip" ^
    ...
    "exit"
```

---

See also other [options for downloading the most recent files](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_download_most_recent_file).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: This runs in my system. get /qwe/asd/tryu/%%TIMESTAMP#yyyymmdd%%*.csv.zip. But any idea how to subtract 1 day from it.

Comment: Fixed 4 files. Which have name pattern like 04262016abc,04262016def,04262016ghi,04262016jkl.

Comment: no.  it is like time stamp of the day like 04242016173153_cpg_aob_detail.csv second file like 04242016173655_fmcg_cob_detail.csv.

Comment: But it have other date folders also like  04172016173153_cpg_aob_detail.csv and  04112016173655_fmcg_cob_detail.csv etc

Comment: Its stopped here...Authenticated.
Starting the session...
Session started.
Active session: [1] abc@****.na.ab.com
P:\Projects\abc\Test_bacth\Batch_download
/qwe/asd/tryu
winscp>

Comment: Error :- Unknown switch 'latest'.

Comment: Thanks . Thank you so much it works. have 2 query more first is how to pass password to it and second can we unzip all 4 folders in a particular folder. Thanks again

Comment: Password: see my edited answer. Unzip: Do not see how's that related. You should probably ask a new question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36865582/how-to-unzip-the-folder-after-downloaded-from-winscp

Comment: How can i run this code when it have space in it.see the download file path                     "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" /command ^
    "open sftp://abc:password@****.na.ab.com/ -hostkey=""ssh-dss 1024 xx:xx:xx:...""" ^
    "lcd \\fastrg01\Olg\DFF abc(25-kml-0234)\VM\ZIP_INPUT" ^
    "cd /qwe/asd/tryu" ^
    "get -latest *_cpg_aob_detail.csv.zip" ^
    "get -latest *_fmcg_cob_detail.csv.zip" ^
    ...
    "exit"

Comment: The same way as with the space in the `-hostkey`, enclose the path with double double-quotes. See my updated answer. And also https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#syntax

Comment: Hi Martin Got stuck in again. This week the client did not put the file in that path so it took the last week file as latest.  Can we make it dynamic so that it can only picks the latest monday date file.  the pattern for monday date is like 06262016173113_cpg_aob_detail.csv.zip and 06262016173113_fmcg_cob_detail.csv.zip. Can we do something of it.

Comment: This is not a discussion forum. If you have a question, [ask it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).